# What does "For" mean in "For Mr. Perlstein..."?

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

I'm currently reading an essay "[Two years are better Than Four](https://essay.blogs.nytimes.com/2007/09/26/two-years-are-better-than-four/)", Liz Addison.

In the third paragraph, third sentence is quite problematic for me.
It's saying:

> **For** Mr. Perlstein, so rooted in his own nostalgia, is looking for himself – and he would never think to look for himself in the one place left where the college experience of self-discovery does still matter to those who get there.

I don't understand what "For" means in this sentence.
Does it mean "because"? or Does it mean "in the shoes of Mr. Perlstein"?
If it possible, I want to know whole meaning of this sentence.

Comment: It means ***because***. The sentence it appears at the start of is *explaining / justifying* the immediately preceding sentence ***But he is wrong.*** Stripped of the "optional" additional clauses, the sentence under consideration means *[He is wrong] **because** although he is "looking for himself", **he's looking in the wrong place***. Note that the whole text is excessively convoluted (it reads like a less-than-perfect writer "showing off" her command of obscure / formal / dated syntax). I wouldn't recommend it for learners.

Comment: I've only just noticed the source of that article. The NYT does feature some "good" writers ([Maureen Dowd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maureen_Dowd) comes to mind), but they also tend to favour some writers who write unnecessarily complicated prose. I think this is because some of their *native speaker* readers get a kick out of *just about* being able to parse and understand the text (a bit like the way I enjoy the intellectual challenge of cryptic crosswords). I certainly don't recommend copying Addison's style - even for the natives, let alone *learners*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's an older usage of the word, meaning "because".